# Multiple Dex files error. Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1

Tags: android, build.gradle, dex, build-error

Please help me out. I have been stuck on this problem for so long. I am getting this error when I build my app

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1;

Here is my app level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.exploro.socialmediaapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0',          {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.2.0'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Start by eliminating all `+` signs  in your `dependencies`, and instead provide the specific versions of the dependencies that you want to use.

Comment: That did not solve it.

Comment: OK. Do you have any JARs in `libs/`?

Comment: No, I don't have any JARs in libs. Its empty.

Comment: OK, so much for the easy solutions. :-( In Android Studio, when you have the project tree set to the Project view, at the bottom of the tree will be a collapsed branch named "External Libraries". If you open that, it will show you all of the dependencies that you are pulling in, including transitive dependencies. If you open those dependencies, you will see `classes.jar` in each, and if you go into those, you will see the Java classes that come from the dependency.

Comment: You are going to need to track down which of these have `android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData`. If I had to guess, you will have two `android.arch.lifecycle` dependencies, with different versions, that each contain `LiveData`. *Then*, you will need to use the Gradle dependency report to determine which dependencies in your `build.gradle` are pulling in those two copies of `LiveData`.

Comment: I checked out the vast dependencies given by gradle projects tab on the right hand side in tasks>android>androidDependencies. In the whole dependency list, each one of it used livedata-core 1.1.0 (the same version)

Answer (score 2):

Just fix firebase ui version to 3.2.2. 
Change

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.2.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

Comment: Firebase recommends using firebase-ui version 2.2.0 with firebaseauth or playservices version 11.0.4 (which i use)

Comment: I use 3.2.2 and seems it is OK. But it is interesting reason for this recommendation. Could you provide link to this recommendation?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Check section "compatibility"

Comment: saved my day :)